# Java GWT - not compiling

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, compilation

i am a freshman at this (GWT) so i have a problem. I cant compile my code and change html files. For instance:

my **HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.client;

import com.tutorialspoint.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        Label myLib1 = new Label("Alllllll");
        Button btn1 = new Button("Touch me");


        vPanel.add(myLib1);vPanel.add(btn1);
        RootPanel.get().add(vPanel);
    }
}
```

my **HelloWolrd.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HelloWorld.css">

    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Web Application Ser Project</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helloworld/helloworld.nocache.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the **result** is :
[image: screenshot]

My prediction is that , maybe eclipse cannot convert java to javascript correctly.

My gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0//EN"
  "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='helloworld'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.tutorialspoint.client.HelloWorld'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

***EDITED:***

AND ALSO I GOT : (this error)

[image]

Comment: added . so no one knows?

Comment: How are you compiling? It is a very basic project. You can simple use GWT plugin installed in the eclipse to run your code.